# Lp-Spaces - find an example

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

On a measure space $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ with $1\le p<r<q\le\infty$ and $f \in L^r(\mu)$, is it possible to find a concrete example with $g \in L^p(\mu)$ and $h \in L^q(\mu)$ with $g+h=f$ and $\vert \vert g \vert \vert _{L^p}+\vert \vert h \vert \vert _{L^q} \le 2 \vert \vert f \vert \vert _{L^r}$   ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about $f=g=h=0$?

Comment: Okay ;) thats the trivial example ;) any more suggestions :)?

Comment: $\mu(\Omega)=1$, $g=h=1$, $f=2$.

Comment: do you think that this is the intention of this exercise?

Comment: Yes, unless the question is more specific.

Comment: no, it shoult work for a given f

Comment: so g and h must depend somewhat on f